# Change location of config files, Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-profiles

By default some programs save their configuration to the `USERPROFILE` folder.
Typically this is

```
C:\Users\Steven
```

I would like to change where these programs are saving these files, possibly

```
C:\Users\Steven\Configs
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a workaround. Create a new user folder.

```
C:\home\Steven
```

Create a Configs folder

```
C:\home\Steven\Configs
```

Symlink to any config files that you want to keep

```
mklink foo.bar C:\home\Steven\Configs\foo.bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The apps are (most likely) writing to the folder by referencing the `%USERPROFILE%` variable.  The user's profile folder is one of the few places they are allowed to write without system/admin intervention.  It's where they're 'supposed' to write to.

Unless you [change the location of your user profile](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/05/how-to-change-user-profile-default-location-in-windows-7/) (hint: check `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`), or the programs themselves, I don't think you're going to be able to accomplish what you seem to want to do.

Comment: You're right, the linked question is not really that great to do what you want, so I've changed it to something a little more appropriate.  The answer itself still stands, they are writing to the USERPROFILE folder, you either need to change the profile folder/location, or change the programs so they write where you want.

Comment: Again, you havent thought your answer through. What exactly would I change my `ProfilesDirectory` to in the registry? Even if I changed it to `C:\Users\Steven\Configs`, the programs would write to `C:\Users\Steven\Configs\Steven`, not to mention this would break any other user profiles that exist.

Answer (score 0):

They are probably (this is my expertise speaking here, which sarcastically means how I would try to do this) located in your environment / path variables. Go to start, type environment variables, and it should take you to the PATH and TEMP variables, where you can change the location. NOTE!: This may make some programs stop working, so be careful, and I warned you if they do stop.